# Question on the definition of automorphic forms

Tags: automorphic-forms

I have a kind of open-ended question on the definitions regarding automorphic forms.

I need to recall some background to explain myself a little bit better. 
Let's consider $G$ a semi-simple group over $Q$, and let $A$ be the adeles of $Q$. Let's focus on the discrete automorphic representations. One way to proceed is to look at the space $L$ of $L^2$-functions on $G(A)/G(Q)$, taking values in $C$, which is a Hilbert space. The group $G(A)$ then acts by translations on $L$. We can now consider the irreducible subrepresentations $\pi$ of $L^2$. These irreducible subrepresentations are not exactly the discrete automorphic representations, but it is very close. Namely, in the literature (see e.g. Borel-Casselman), one defines a certain dense subspace $X$ of functions in $L^2$, called "automorphic forms". Then, instead of working with $\pi$, one works with $X \cap \pi$. My question: What is the point of taking this intersection?

(If I understand correctly), by density, $\pi$ can be recovered from $X \cap \pi$ by taking the closure in the $L^2$-space. So $X \cap \pi$ and $\pi$ carry the same amount of information?

The $G(A)$-representation $\pi$ should have some level, which is a compact open subgroup $K \subset G(A)$ such that $\pi^K$ is non-zero. Could it be that, unlike in the case where we would look at $(X \cap \pi)^K$, the space $\pi^K$ could be infinite dimensional? Is this one of the reasons to consider $\pi \cap X$ instead of $\pi$?

One important property of automorphic representations is Flath's tensor product decomposition. Maybe this decomposition fails if you work with $\pi$ instead of $X \cap \pi$? Although I am not really sure, because my feeling is that you can take the tensor product decomposition of $X \cap \pi$, and then complete all the local representations that appear there, and then get a decomposition of $\pi$ ?

Comment: Think about this just for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$; the space $L^2(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H})$ has a spectral decomposition such that it is spanned by Maass cusp forms and generalised Eisenstein series. But $L^2$-functions are only defined up to sets of measure zero, whereas automorphic forms should be smooth! So we start with the subspace of smooth automorphic forms, which are dense, and take the $L^2$-completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this question is very much on the mark, a sort of "emperor's new clothes" question/issue. Indeed, to meta-explain to my own research students the folly of "defining" automorphic forms in any one of the usual (and orthodox) ways (e.g., smooth, K-finite, $\mathfrak z$-finite, moderate growth), I ask them, "so not everything in $L^2(\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak H)$ is an automorphic form?" And about distributions not being any kind of automorphic form?

Well, sure, we like smooth functions better than not-so-smooth, etc., but/and this "definition" is best when used only to refer to the *individual*, *special* automorphic forms/functions (that do span, one way or another, the $L^2$ space and others).

That is, just as the exponentials (or sines and cosines) are very nice functions on the circle, certainly not every $L^2$ function on the circle is as nice. But we still do have reasons to care about $L^2$.

In the case of automorphic things, we might care about spectral decompositions of Poincar\'e series of various sorts, especially (!) some made from not-so-smooth functions, to achieve better outcomes (by the typical irony). Similarly, we might care about genuine proofs of trace formulas and relative trace formulas, not only for "smooth, compactly-supported" data-inputs, but more generally, and the most interesting cases are analytically the least trivial. So there is considerable reason to care about analytically "awkward" situations.

As in the simplest-possible case of Fourier series, the individual exponential functions are very nicely behaved. No doubt. But the convergence of Fourier series is a highly non-trivial topic.